# C: modify regex implementation to be able to find regex anywhere within a string

Tags: c, regex, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a regex implementation using dynamic programming but it only works if it's being compared to an input string `s` and the regex `p` is the ending of `s`. For example, for input string `s = "teeeeeest"` and regex `p = "te*st"` will be a match. However, if there are any characters after s: `s = "teeeeeeeesthihi"` it will not be a match. Another simple example is: `aab` and `aa` won't match. How can I modify my DP approach so that it returns a match if regex exists anywhere within the basestring `s`?

My dp approach (based on a leetcode approach but I modified it and added explanations):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool match(char a, char b)
{
    return b == '.' || a == b;
}

bool isMatch(char *s, char *p)
{

    // Use an dpay to log matching status as we move
    // dp[i] = 1 if and only if s.substr(0, i) matches the current regex

    int sLen = strlen(s);
    int pLen = strlen(p);
    int position = 0, result = 0, matched = 0;
    bool dp[sLen + 1];

    /* 
        initially our regex is ""
        we set dp to [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...] because
        the only substring matches "" is s.substr(0, 0), which is an empty string
    */

    memset(dp + 1, 0, sLen);
    *dp = 1;

    /* we scan through p to extend our regex and update dp */
    while (*p)
    {
        printf("printing dp\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < sLen + 1; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", dp[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // reg is previous regex, c is next character (p[0])
        // dp[i] is previous index, dp[i + 1] is current index
        // because of the empty case "" offset index by 1

        if (p[1] == '?')
        {
            // explanation:
            // if we have a ?
            // then set dp[i] to 1 if:
            // 1) s[i] == p[i] match, dp[i] == 1, s.len is 1 more than p.len (single case)
            // 2) s[i] != p[i], dp[i] == 1, s.len 1 more than p.len (none case)

            // case 1
            if (match(s[position], *p) && dp[position])
            {
                dp[position + 1] = 1;
                position += 2;
            } // case 2
            else if (!match(s[position], *p) && dp[position] == 1)
                dp[position + 1] = 1;

            p++;
        }
        else if (p[1] == '*')
        {
            // explanation:
            // if we see asterick in the next char, that means we have to loop
            // this char (p[0]) and check against every single char in s.
            // Set matching current char (dp[i + 1]) to 1 if it matches
            for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++)
            {
                // explanation:
                // setting the current char to true means that
                // all previous characters matched regex and
                // the current character matches too
                result = (dp[i] || match(s[i], *p));

                // if *, add 1 to position to skip *
                if (result)
                    position++;
                dp[i + 1] = result;
            }

            // increment pointer to skip the *
            p++;
        }
        else
        {
            // explanation:
            // we go backwards to take care of non * character hagglers
            // and make sure they correspond in s and p
            for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++)
            {
                if (!(*(p + 1)) && dp[sLen - i])
                    return true;
                // explanation:
                // check respective endings in p and s, if they match, set
                // dp[i] to 1 if s[i] and *p match and dp[i - 1] match (means that
                // everything until this index also matched
                result = dp[sLen - i - 1] && match(s[sLen - i - 1], *p);
                // for every non * and ? char, add 1 to position
                if (result)
                    position++;
                dp[sLen - i] = result;
            }

            // get rid of base case(dp[0] = 1) since we now have matches
            dp[0] = 0;
        }

        // go to next p character
        p++;
    }
    // return dp[sLen] since that tells us if s matched p
    if (dp[sLen])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (isMatch(argv[1], argv[2]))
        printf("isssa match\n");
    else
        printf("issa not match \n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: When you get to the end of the regexp, if everything has been matched you should return successs. You don't have to get to the end of the input string.

Comment: What you do mean exactly? `s` and 'p' can be different lengths, and if I reach the end of `p` but not yet the end of `s`, then the whole string wouldn't have been looked at. I guess im just stuck on how I can create a sliding window and check substrings within `s` and if i find a match i return.

Comment: The point is that you don't have to look at the whole string, since a regexp can match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

#### Looks great so far!

- Most likely you have to somehow manipulate the `s` length and `p` length in your DP solution, not exactly sure where in the code though.
- Here is a C++ implementation (but I understand that's a C issue), yet this'd be a bit more concise dynamic programming solution (might help you to reduce the code first).

#### C++ 1-D dynamic programming

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


static const struct Solution {
    static const bool isMatch(
        const std::string base_string,
        const std::string pattern
    ) {
        std::vector<bool> curr(std::size(pattern) + 1, false);

        for (std::size_t base_i = 0; base_i <= std::size(base_string); base_i++) {
            bool prev = curr[0];
            curr[0] = !base_i;

            for (std::size_t patt_j = 1; patt_j <= std::size(pattern); patt_j++) {
                bool temp = curr[patt_j];

                if (pattern[patt_j - 1] == '*') {
                    curr[patt_j] = curr[patt_j - 2] ||
                                   (base_i && curr[patt_j] && (
                                        base_string[base_i - 1] == pattern[patt_j - 2] ||
                                        pattern[patt_j - 2] == '.'
                                    )
                                   );

                } else {
                    curr[patt_j] = base_i && prev && (
                                       base_string[base_i - 1] == pattern[patt_j - 1] ||
                                       pattern[patt_j - 1] == '.'
                                   );
                }

                prev = temp;
            }
        }

        return curr[std::size(pattern)];
    }
};
```

We can also simply use `int`:

```
struct Solution {
    bool isMatch(
        std::string base_string,
        std::string pattern
    ) {
        std::vector<bool> curr(std::size(pattern) + 1, false);

        for (int base_i = 0; base_i <= std::size(base_string); base_i++) {
            bool prev = curr[0];
            curr[0] = !base_i;

            for (int patt_j = 1; patt_j <= std::size(pattern); patt_j++) {
                bool temp = curr[patt_j];

                if (pattern[patt_j - 1] == '*') {
                    curr[patt_j] = curr[patt_j - 2] ||
                                   (base_i && curr[patt_j] && (
                                        base_string[base_i - 1] == pattern[patt_j - 2] ||
                                        pattern[patt_j - 2] == '.'
                                    )
                                   );

                } else {
                    curr[patt_j] = base_i && prev && (
                                       base_string[base_i - 1] == pattern[patt_j - 1] ||
                                       pattern[patt_j - 1] == '.'
                                   );
                }

                prev = temp;
            }
        }

        return curr[std::size(pattern)];
    }
};
```

#### C using Recursion

Here is a C version however not based on dynamic programming (just using recursion), is a bit slow though:

```
bool isMatch(
    const char *s,
    const char *p
) {
    int advance_pattern = 1;

    if (*p == 0) {
        return *s == 0;
    }

    if (*p != NULL && *(p + 1) && *(p + 1) == '*') {
        if (isMatch(s, p + 2)) {
            return 1;
        } advance_pattern = 0;
    }

    if (*s != NULL && *p == '.' || *s == *p) {
        return isMatch(s + 1, p + advance_pattern);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Java 2-D dynamic programming

```
public class Solution {
    public static final boolean isMatch(
        final String s,
        final String p
    ) {
        if (s == null || p == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean[][] dp = new boolean[s.length() + 1][p.length() + 1];
        dp[0][0] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
            if (p.charAt(i) == '*' && dp[0][i - 1]) {
                dp[0][i + 1] = true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < p.length(); j++) {
                if (p.charAt(j) == '.') {
                    dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j];
                }

                if (p.charAt(j) == s.charAt(i)) {
                    dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j];
                }

                if (p.charAt(j) == '*')
                    if (p.charAt(j - 1) != s.charAt(i) && p.charAt(j - 1) != '.') {
                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i + 1][j - 1];
                    }

                    else {
                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = (dp[i + 1][j] || dp[i][j + 1] || dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
                    }
            }
        }

        return dp[s.length()][p.length()];
    }
}
```

#### Python using a Regular Expression

Of course we would not be allowed to use the `re` package (just for the contests):

```
class Solution:
    def isMatch(self, s, pattern):
        try:
            return re.match('^' + pattern + '$', s)
        except:
            return False
```

Comment: While trying to compile and test the code, I get an error of "size is not a member of the std class." It seems like on the lines where you have `std::size_t` it is failing. How would I get around this( I have never used C++)

Comment: Yep it would. Thank you for the help thus far but I intended to bring the leetcode solution one step farther (since the LC questino/solution assumes that the basestring has no additional characters). I want to be able to find a regular expression pattern within any string, even if there are trailing letters or characters.
For eg, `aab` doesnt match `aa` based on the Leetcode solution, but I want to return a match since the pattern `aa` exists within `aab`

Comment: Thank you! I will add that tag.